# How do you properly implement regression with categorical explanatory variables missing values when gtsummary tbl_uvregression?

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am using `tbl_uvregression` doing logistic regression but some of the categorical explanatory variables have missing values. The missing value category is being chosen as the reference category. How do I implement the function such that I only use complete cases for each variable?

Sample data below

`structure(list(time = structure(c(5, 42, 23, 3, 26, 1, 7, 28,  5, 2, 1, 3, 23, 3, 11, 4, 2, 36, 2, 4, 53, 4, 5, 64, 14, 4, 5,  3, 31, 10, 26, 39, 4, 24, 4, 4, 6, 21, 15, 5, 3, 9, 3, 29, 63,  2, 1, 1, 16, 9, 3, 24, 1, 9, 23, 1, 6, 4, 6, 22, 57, 18, 11,  5, 9, 40, 3, 9, 1, 5, 6, 4, 12, 13, 19, 3, 6, 9, 1, 3, 29, 5,  4, 47, 33, 31, 1, 10, 18, 3, 9, 7, 42, 5, 16, 52, 1, 5, 1, 3,  5, 5, 9, 8, 17, 4, 21, 1, 22, 12, 3, 19, 10, 1, 10, 10, 1, 9,  1, 13, 8, 14, 2, 1, 32, 9, 17, 1, 5, 1, 6, 7, 7, 28, 5, 8, 33,  2, 1, 4, 1, 31, 1, 1, 45, 5, 4, 11, 1, 8, 1, 21, 8, 14, 1, 1,  3, 1, 12, 4, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 21, 2, 1, 3, 8, 12, 7, 1, 6,  9, 12, 3, 1, 6, 1, 8, 3, 21, 3), format.stata = "%10.0g"), OutcomeDischarge0Death1 = structure(c(0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,  0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,  1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), label = "Outcome (Discharge = 0, Death = 1)", format.stata = "%10.0g"),  HTN = structure(c(1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L,  3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L,  1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L,  1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L,  3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L,  3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L,  3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L,  3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("N",  "", "Y"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -186L), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame"))`

`surv$HTN <- forcats::fct_relevel(neil$HTN, "N")`

```
  tbl_uvregression(
    neil[c("time", "OutcomeDischarge0Death1", "HTN")],
    method = coxph,
    y = Surv(time, OutcomeDischarge0Death1),
    exponentiate = TRUE,
    pvalue_fun = function(x) style_pvalue(x, digits = 2)
  )%>%
```

Comment: Can you provide an example we can all run our machines? By default only complete cases are included in the models, so I am not sure what is happening on your machine.

Comment: Apologies@DanielSjoberg, I have now added the data

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is there are no missing values in the column `HTN`. There are, however, 4 observations that are blank, but this is not missing.

[image]

If you first make the empty string an NA (aka missing), then those observations will be omitted from the model.

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(survival)

neil %>%
  # make the missing string NA (aka missing)
  dplyr::mutate(HTN = ifelse(HTN == "", NA, HTN)) %>%
  # building univariate regression models
  tbl_uvregression(
    method = coxph,
    y = Surv(time, OutcomeDischarge0Death1),
    exponentiate = TRUE,
    pvalue_fun = function(x) style_pvalue(x, digits = 2)
  )
```

[image]

Happy Programming!

Comment: Thanks, missed one there!